# Looping through a .KML file and Finding Values in Side a Particular Node?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, kml

I have a .kml file which I am unable to parse through the SharpKml assemblies; probably the format is not compatible--certainly, there is a lot of junk in the file.

But I have found out that I can use `XDocument.Load()` function in a C# console application and see that loaded document. So I am planning to use standard .NET xml functions to parse the .kml file. I think I should be able to do that?

Basically, I am interested in parsing the `<PlaceMark>` node which exists along with the junk/un-needed data. Here is the structure of the node:

```
<Placemark>
    <Snippet></Snippet>
    <styleUrl>#style0</styleUrl>
    <ExtendedData>
        <SchemaData schemaUrl="#Bracket_Hall_RoomData">
            <SimpleData name="FID">0</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Room">230C</SimpleData>      
        </SchemaData>
    </ExtendedData>
    <Polygon>
        <extrude>false</extrude>
        <tessellate>false</tessellate>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
                <extrude>false</extrude>
                <tessellate>false</tessellate>
                <coordinates>-82.836315,34.678898,0.000000 -82.836317,34.678886,0.000000...</coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
</Placemark>
```

Again, there will be multiple such nodes in the document. I have looked at other code samples but they are too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions is a little vague in terms of what you're trying to do. You say you want to parse the `<Placemark>` node but there may be additional `<Placemark>` nodes among the "junk" in the file. It's unclear whether you want all the `<Placemark>` nodes or a specific one. So, taking a guess, once you've loaded the XML into the XDocument you can issue a LINQ-to-XML query to get all the `<Placemark>` nodes.

```
var placemarks =
    (from x in xDoc.Descendants()
     where x.Name.LocalName == "Placemark"
     select new XElement(x)).ToList();
```

You can now loop over the `placemarks` variable (which is a collection) and do what you need to with each. This is a very simple implementation, assuming there is only one fid, room, and coordinates node per placemark.

```
foreach (var placemark in placemarks)
{
    var fid = (from x in placemark.Descendants("SimpleData")
               where x.Attribute("name").Value == "FID"
               select x).First().Value;
    var room = (from x in placemark.Descendants("SimpleData")
                where x.Attribute("name").Value == "Room"
                select x).First().Value;
    var coord = (from x in placemark.Descendants("coordinates")
                 select x).First().Value;
}
```

Comment: Hi,Yes, I needed all Placemark nodes; I will try your code. Any hint as to how to loop through each Placemark node and output node name/value?

Comment: Looping is easy, use a `for` or `foreach` loop. What value are you talking about? The `<Placemark>` node doesn't have a value, it has a bunch of child nodes.

Comment: I will need values of FID, ROOM, and Coordinates. Thx. I have Accepted your answer.

Comment: Craig. Thanks so much for the looping code too. I am just about exhausted from the failed attempts with the SharpKml way otherwise would have figured out. Thanks again! This is a big help.